# How to have a constexpr pointer to CMSIS defined hardware peripheral?

Tags: c++, constexpr, memory-mapped-io

I want to use `constexpr` instead of `#define`s wherever possible, for type safety and namespace features.

Unfortunately, I get this `error: 'reinterpret_cast<SPI_TypeDef*>(1073756160)' is not a constant expression` when trying.

```
#include <stm32f0xx.h> // #defines SPI2 as pointer to a struct of volatile unsigned ints

constexpr auto myPort = SPI2;
```

I'm **not** looking for an explanation of why `reinterperet_cast` cannot be used in a `constexpr`.

What is the modern C++ way to have a constexpr pointer to some memory mapped hardware?

One reason for this is to use these `constexpr` values in templated code.

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` code wasn't invented so that you could avoid using `#define`s; it's there so that you can do certain things with expressions that you couldn't otherwise. You can pass `constexpr` pointers or integers as template parameters, for example, since they are constant expressions.

Basically, the primary purpose of any `constexpr` variable or function is to be able to be used within compile-time programming. So to declare a variable to be `constexpr` is to say "this is a compile-time constant and it's reasonable to use it at compile-time."

A pointer whose value is an arbitrary address cannot be used at compile-time. So marking such a pointer as a compile-time value is a contradiction. So you're not allowed to do it. `constexpr` pointers are required to be real pointers, which are either null pointers or point to actual objects. Not to arbitrary addresses.

Comment: This is exactly why I'd like to use `constexpr`. I'd love to be able to write templated code that takes a pointer as the template argument. Where the pointer points is *known* at compile time. That's the whole point of memory mapped hardware. Any offsets from that base address are also known at compile time. Of course the value pointed to by those pointers cannot be known at compile time. That's why the pointers are `constexpr` to `volatile uint32_t`. But comparing those pointers, for instance, could absolutely happen at compile time.

Comment: @CameronTacklind: But it's not a pointer *to* anything; it's just a number. In constexpr coding, pointers aren't addresses; they point at objects. The C++ object model is *real* in constexpr code, so you can't just make up a number and pretend that it's a meaningful pointer. They can only point at an object or null. "*That's the whole point of memory mapped hardware.*" Your compiler can't do "memory mapped hardware".

Comment: @CameronTacklind: If you'd "love to be able to write templated code that takes a pointer as the template argument." - you better update your question accordingly to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Even `std::bit_cast`, which can in certain cases emulate `reinterpret_cast` at compile-time, [loses its constexpr-ness](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) when one of the involved types is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers already state, it is not possible for arbitrary pointers.

If it is "for type safety and namespace features [...] to some memory mapped hardware" you are asking for, why you don't just use

```cpp
// assumed preconditions, since not provided in question
typedef struct {
  volatile unsigned int a;
  volatile unsigned int b;
} SPI_TypeDef;

SPI_TypeDef* SPI2 = (SPI_TypeDef*)0x12345678;

// actual answer
SPI_TypeDef* const myPort = SPI2;
```

This way your **pointer** myPort to some data of type struct *SPI_TypeDef* is const, but not the pointed-to struct.

`const` keyword is generally "left-assigning".

Comment: `error: cannot convert 'SPI_TypeDef*' to 'volatile unsigned int* const' in initialization`

Comment: You may provide the code excerpt where `SPI2` is defined. I assume it is a simple integral `#define` for a memory location (i.e. pointer). If it is already typed as `SPI_TypeDef*` you may better use `SPI_TypeDef* const = SPI2`.